# Number of Clock Cycles between events in SV

Tags: system-verilog, clock

I want to calculate the number of clock cycles between a signal's high and low value. I have a signal SIG, it goes high and low multiple times during a simulation. I would like to calculate the average number of cycles when it's high/low.

Can someone please guide me how to achieve it.Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Are you asking how to build hardware that make this calculation, or are you just trying to analyze the signal in simulation?

Comment: Analyze the signal. I want to write a logic that just capture write signal and clock. and calculate on an average how many clock cycles does each write/read takes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a counter for the clock cycles, starting to count when the signal `SIG` is high, and stop counting when `SIG` goes low, in order to measure the number of clock cycles while `SIG` = "1":

```
int counter = 0; // counter initialization
@(posedge SIG); // waits for SIG to go high
while(SIG == 1) begin // while SIG = "1"
      @(posedge CLK); // when clock signal gets high
      counter++; // increase counter by 1
end
```

You could do the same while `SIG` = "0", with `@(negedge SIG);`.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is put a count the number of cycles each value is high/low and put them into a queue. Then average them out at the finish.

```
module top;
   bit sig, clk;

   int hiCount[$]={0}, loCount[$]={0};

   always #5 clk++;

   always @(negedge clk) // 5:1 chance of keeping the same value
     randomize(sig) with {sig == const'(sig) dist { 1 := 5, 0 := 1 }; };

   always @(posedge clk) begin
      case(sig)
    1: if ($stable(sig))
      hiCount[$]++;
    else
      hiCount.push_back(1); // first cycle high
    0: if ($stable(sig))
      loCount[$]++;
    else
      loCount.push_back(1); // first cycle low
      endcase // case (sig)
      $display("sig: %0d\nhi:%p\nlo: %p",sig,hiCount,loCount);
      end
   initial begin
      repeat(100) @(posedge clk);
      if (loCount[0] == 0) void'(loCount.pop_front());
      if (hiCount[0] == 0) void'(hiCount.pop_front());

      $display("sig was high %0d times with average cycle count of %0d",
           hiCount.size(), hiCount.sum()/hiCount.size);
            $display("sig was low %0d times with average cycle count of %0d",
           loCount.size(), loCount.sum()/loCount.size);
      $finish;
   end
endmodule // top
```